# How to return a value based on a property of a list of objects using streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I need to return the name (String) of the Person record with shortest height using streams.

I have searched online but all i could find that kind of worked was finding the actual lowest int value, not the name of the Person with the lowest height. i just started learning streams and i find them so hard to understand. Any help is appreciated.

```
//Can not use for/while/if/shortestPerson
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.function.*;

record Person(String name, int height) {
}

public class Exercise {
    // this is where the implementation goes 
    static String shortestPerson(List<Person> ps) {
               String name= ps.stream().map.name.
    
  }

    static Person p(String name, int height) {
        return new Person(name, height);
    }

    static void test(String expected, List<Person> input) {
        String res = shortestPerson(input);
        assert res.equals(expected) : "For input " + input + " we get " + res + " instead of " + expected;
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        try {
            shortestPerson(List.of());
            assert false;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        }

        test("Bob", List.of(p("Bob", 190)));
        test("Adam", List.of(p("Adam", 220)));
        test("Alice", List.of(p("Bob", 190), p("Alice", 170)));
        test("Bob", List.of(p("Bob", 170), p("Alice", 190)));
        test("Bob", List.of(p("Bob", 1), p("Alice", 2), p("Dany", 3)));
        test("Dany", List.of(p("Bob", 3), p("Alice", 2), p("Dany", 1)));
        test("Alice", List.of(p("Bob", 3), p("Alice", 2), p("Dany", 5)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```java
static String shortestPerson(List<Person> ps) {
    return ps.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Person::height)).orElse(new Person("No One", 0)).name;
}
```

Comment: Calling `map` will remove the need to make up a dummy Person object.

Answer (score 0):

In your `shortestPerson` method, you can do it like this. `Map` is a method of `Optional` which will take the `Object` and extract a different value.

```
static String shortestPerson(List<Person> ps) {
     return ps.stream().min(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::height))
             .map(Person::name).get();
    
 }
```